# Styling just comments inside a `pre` or `code` block with CSS

Tags: html, css, markdown

Is there a way to style comments inside a `pre` or `code` block (e.g. Ruby comments) using only CSS?

For example:

```
# I am a comment and should be lighter and italic
I = { :am => :normal_code, :and_want_no => :special_treatment }
```

I know you can use Javascript/jQuery to insert `<span>` elements in the right spots (like the `<span>`'s in the comment above provided by Stack Overflow) but can it be done **with just CSS**?

For background, I use a markdown renderer which outputs simple `<pre>` and `<code>` elements where necessary but without any hooks for indicating which language you're using and how to flag comments with `<span>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

This task *can't* be done with just CSS.

CSS works at the element level and it is [*not possible* to "select into" general text](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) - even trivially, much less applying some rules to parse language grammar.

As noted, and as seen by inspecting the SO code rendering such as the one in this post, one approach is to output spans with the appropriate CSS classes (which are the result of separate grammar processing) - then these individual spans, which can selected, are styled.

Answer (score 0):

- a) What markdown renderer?
- b) This can't be done with CSS with classes or ID's, as well as `psuedo
  elements`

### I will expand further as you do.

The problem is, you can't exactly render `comments` with your provided method, **as these are technically never rendered in the first place.**

`comments` are meant to be **non-runnable code** to help for `debugging`. Trying to `add comments` or `manipulate comments` would be a security breach and would require actually `inserting a file` into your appreciable code.

As far as that would go? That would be a tricky scenario unless you had the same `comment` or multiple files available to do so. I would say to just `import your file` if necessary with a duplicate version with a `comment`ed version.

Comment: I'm using the Redcarpet gem for markdown and can't get the prettify option to work.

Comment: To be honest, I can tell you one thing. As far as I know, comments are not cacheable. But it looks like you're using an **API** I'm not familiar with. In all honesty, comments are **MEANT** to be skipped by the interpreter. You may be at a standstill... ever thought of caching your `comments` to an `object` and calling them that way?