# Is it possible to have multiple fonts in one div?

Tags: html, css

For example, in one line there will be 2 different fonts for different words.

i.e

```
(typeworthy) This is a (helvetica) test
```

Typeworthy being on 'This is a' and helvetica being on 'test'. Not sure how to do this though - I've tried using different div classes but that puts the words on different lines.

Can this be done?

**Update:**

view:

```
  <span class="font1">We</span> <span class="font2">LOVE</span>
   <span class="font3">Flappy Bird</span><span class="fontone">so much<div id="space">we made <span class="fonttwo">FLAPPY</span>, the toy game controller!</span></div>
```

css:

```
.font1{

    font-family: 'boxyfont';
    text-shadow: -1px -1px white, -1px 1px white, 2px -1px white, -1px -1px white;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}

.font2{
    font-family: 'noteworthy';
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    margin-top:-10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes div#someID { font-family: Arial; }
div#someID:first-line { font-family: whatever }

Comment: @KRUKUSA Why did post an answer as a comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here try this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/M2mjS/)

```
<div>
    <span class="font1">Hello</span> <span class="font2">World</span> !
</div>

.font1{
    font-family:serif;
}
.font2{
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks! Is it possible to elevate 'World'? So that World is a little higher than Hello?

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! This is what I'm trying to accomplish http://imgur.com/JUVHyRG. In addition, I've updated the original post with the code I have using your method, but the 'LOVE' font isn't raised/working 100% unfortunately. What am i doing wrong? :(

Comment: Can you your test website or a fiddle ?

Comment: Well, that's my fiddle. I meant your site, so I can see what's the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Use a span:

```
<p>
  <span class="typeworthy">This is a</span> <span class="helvetica">Test</span>
</p>
```

Then, configure the two classes on your css.

You might want to use the `<em>` instead, if the reason for the difference is to give emphasis.

Answer (score 1):

```
div {
   font-family:Arial;
}
span {
   font-family:Verdana;
}

<div>
    some text
    <span>some other text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `span` tag around each section where the font is specified, and keep them in the same `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<span>` tag inside the div.

```
<div style="font-family:Times">
    This is text in Times New Roman.
    <span style="font-family:sans-serif">
        <br/> This is in sans-serif.
    </span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/e325K/)

Answer (score 0):

Only *one* value of any particular CSS attribute, including fonts, may be applied *per element*. (The CSS specifity rules determine exactly which value is applied, but it can be only be a single value and there are [no "sub element" CSS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21396743/styling-just-comments-inside-a-pre-or-code-block-with-css).)

As others have pointed out, there can be many different (non-div/inline) elements *within* the div - these *individual* elements can themselves have different CSS values applied.

Inspecting the SO markup for "code text" reveals that it uses *many* spans for the different colors (different values for a single CSS attribute), which can be considered different fonts for the same of argument.

For instance,

```cs
(typeworthy) This is a (helvetica) test
```

Is rendered as the following, where each class rule may have a different color (think: font) applied.

```
<code>
  <span class="pun">(</span>
  <span class="pln">typeworthy</span>
  <span class="pun">)</span>
  <span class="pln"> </span>
  <span class="typ">This</span>
  ..
</code>
```